# Secure text i.e. password not display's as vertical centre for UITextfield in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

When I entered the password(secure text) in UITextField, dots are not display's in vertical centre even though UITextField text alignment property is set as vertically and horizontally centre.Find the screen shot for better understanding.

[image]